# Why is Blueimp jQuery File Upload renaming directory when uploading?

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload, blueimp, codeigniter-3

This is a strange bug I've found. When my users upload multiple pictures it all works smoothly, except sometimes the 'tmp directory' where images are uploaded to server gets renamed to the image file name, causing the rest of images to fail upload, because 'tmp' no longer exists.

It's very weird and I can't reproduce this error. I was wondering if this has happened to anybody else and may know the reason.

I'm using Codeigniter 3 as well.

Here is the code of my do_upload function:

```
public function do_upload()
{
    $upload_path_url = base_url() . 'imagen/tmp/';

    $config['upload_path'] = FCPATH . 'imagen/tmp/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';
    $config['max_size'] = '30000';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        //$this->load->view('upload', $error);
        $this->output
        ->set_content_type('application/json')
        ->set_output(json_encode($error));

    } else {
        $data = $this->upload->data();
        // to re-size for thumbnail images un-comment and set path here and in json array
        $config = array();
        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config['source_image'] = $data['full_path'];
        $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
        $config['new_image'] = $data['file_path'] . 'thumbs/';
        $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        $config['thumb_marker'] = '';
        $config['width'] = 75;
        $config['height'] = 50;
        $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
        $this->image_lib->resize();

        //set the data for the json array
        $info = new StdClass;
        $info->name = $data['file_name'];
        $info->size = $data['file_size'] * 1024;
        $info->type = $data['file_type'];
        $info->url = $upload_path_url . $data['file_name'];
        // ruta thumb para preview
        $info->thumbnailUrl = $upload_path_url . 'thumbs/' . $data['file_name'];
        $info->deleteUrl = base_url() . 'notas/deleteImage/' . $data['file_name'];
        $info->deleteType = 'DELETE';
        $info->error = null;

        $files[] = $info;
        //this is why we put this in the constants to pass only json data
        if (IS_AJAX) {
            echo json_encode(array("files" => $files));
        } else {
            $file_data['upload_data'] = $this->upload->data();
            // TODO:
            $this->load->view('upload/upload_success', $file_data);
        }
    }
}
```

Please if anybody knows the cause of this I would greatly appreciate it. Can't tell you the headache it is giving my team and me to figure it out.

Comment: Docs doesn't say anything about `$config['new_image']` attribute.

Comment: I got it off an example code, should I take it out?

Comment: @Tpojka Here is a link to docs with the 'new_image' attribute [link](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/jQuery-File-Upload,---Multi-file-upload-with-CodeIgniter)

Comment: You should mention that link already. Do you test it on fresh installation of CodeIgniter. Also, I can notice CI v2.x is used in repository.

Comment: @Tpojka I followed many tutorials not just that one. Both the image library and file upload library work the same in CI 3, so it gave me no problem when implementing. This bug is not frequent, it has only happened twice in about 6 months, but we can't figure out why :(